# In Rails 3 how to query across a has one assositation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, join, has-one

In rails 3, I have accounts and users, it looks like this:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :owner, :class_name => "User", :dependent => :destroy
end
```

I have something like this but it doesn't work, I want to join on the owner association and order and what not by it:

```
Account.includes(:owner).where(["owner.email = ?", "hello@gmail.com"])
```

What's the correct way of going about this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
Account.includes(:owner).where("users.email=?", "hello@gmail.com")
```

The condition should use the table_name

Answer (score 0):

The right thing would be to do like this:-

```
Account.joins(:owner).where(["owner.email = ?", "hello@gmail.com"]).includes(:owner)
```